# Sort NSArray by date and time

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, nsarray, nssortdescriptor

This may be a duplicate question, but i have a strange issue, So that i have pasted it on stack.

I have a issue while sorting `NSArray` by date and time.

For example, I have below fields in Database file:-

```
id        Name       Date
1         ABC        2015-01-29 16:36:31
2         AAA        2015-01-29 16:36:31
3         BBB        2015-01-29 16:36:31
4         CCC        2015-01-29 16:36:31
5         DDD        2015-01-29 16:36:31
```

Note :- Datatype of Date filed is Timestamp in **sqlite Database** and i am storing it as NSDate while fetching data.

Now, I am sorting this data as below through NSArray

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDesc = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:kContentEditedDate ascending:NO];
        NSArray *sortDescAry = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDesc];
        contentData = [contentData sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescAry];
```

Above code just display descending order even each row has same date.

After that i also tried `[NSArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:]` to sorting it also display same result as first option.

I tried to edit date of last row in database and run query as below:

```
SELECT RelImgName,EditedDate FROM "tableName"  ORDER BY "EditedDate" DESC;
```

it give me proper output.
As Below:

```
id        Name       Date
 5         DDD        2015-02-02 11:05:32
 1         ABC        2015-01-29 16:36:31
 2         AAA        2015-01-29 16:36:31
 3         BBB        2015-01-29 16:36:31
 4         CCC        2015-01-29 16:36:31
```

But while i am doing this with NSSortDescriptor it display only descending order.

I want output as above with NSSortDescriptor.

Now i hope you all can understand my question.

I search a lot but didn't get any proper solution for it.

Comment: How do you want the array to be sorted if it has the same date?

Comment: If it is same date than it ll give me as no data found otherwise it ll display the object of edited date.

Comment: your question is not clear..

Comment: already your date is same , if u need the comparison use **Name** field

Comment: @ShantiK :- In my DB Rows, all rows are with same date, than also it display as descending order, I dont want it. If it is edited than and than it ll display as recently edited.

Comment: So you need to add a flag to specify that it has been recently edited and do the needful

Comment: Okkkk... i ll inform u..

Comment: @Er.ShreyanshShah: Not able to understand your question properly...

Comment: @Manthan :- While I am firing query of sorting with order by, it give me proper result, but when i used NSSortDescriptor it's not giving me proper output.