# How to sort the Array that contains date in strings in ascending order

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have array of dictionaries ,In every dictionary contains one date parameter . The array of date parameters(contains in dictionaries) as follow:

```
 [@"16-1-2015 7:00PM",@"15-1-2014 11:30AM",@"14-1-2014 7:00PM",
 @"15-1-2015 6:30AM ".@"16-1-2015 8:30PM"]
```

I need output like :

```
[@"16-1-2015 8:30PM",@"16-1-2015 7:00PM",@"15-1-2015 6:30AM ",
@"15-1-2014 11:30AM",@"14-1-2014 7:00PM"];
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28271322/sort-nsarray-by-date-and-time  -

Comment: @ravikanth manne please go through this link .hope it helps you...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132806/sort-nsarray-of-date-strings-or-objects

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
NSArray *dateStringArray = @[ @"16-1-2015 7:00PM", @"15-1-2014 11:30AM", @"14-1-2014 7:00PM", @"15-1-2015 6:30AM ", @"16-1-2015 8:30PM" ];

 - (NSArray *)sortDateStringArray:(NSArray *)dateStringArray
    {
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormater = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormater setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy h:mma"];
        NSArray *sortedArray = [dateStringArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSString *obj1, NSString *obj2) {
          NSDate *date1 = [dateFormater dateFromString:obj1];
          NSDate *date2 = [dateFormater dateFromString:obj2];
          return [date2 compare:date1];
        }];
        return sortedArray;
    }
```

I think it better convert your dateString to NSDate then compare 
Hope this help !!!

Comment: Note that if you swap the compare operands, you can eliminate the switch statement:  `return [date2 compare:date1];`  Also note that constructing `NSDateFormatter` is an expensive operation, at a minimum it should be elevated to outside the block.

Comment: Thanks man. Saved my day. @HuyNghia : Just a heads up, the above code is for sorting in descending order. To make it ascending sort, just replace date1 with date2 on this line: return [date2 compare:date1];

Answer (score 0):

Store the dates as `NSDate` objects in an `NSMutableArray`, then use `-[NSArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:] or -[NSMutableArray sortUsingSelector:]` and pass `@selector(compare:)` as the parameter. The `-[NSDate compare:]` method will order dates in ascending order for you. This is simpler than creating an `NSSortDescriptor`, and much simpler than writing your own comparison function. (`NSDate` objects know how to compare themselves to each other at least as efficiently as we could hope to accomplish with custom code.)

Or

If I have an `NSMutableArray` of objects with a field "beginDate" of type `NSDate` I am using an `NSSortDescriptor` as below:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"beginDate" ascending:TRUE];
[myMutableArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
[sortDescriptor release];
```

please visit this question: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132806/sort-nsarray-of-date-strings-or-objects)